# How to find configure option/glags used to create makefile for the gcc I'm using?

Tags: gcc, toolchain, gnu-toolchain

I have got the mips-gcc toolchain source code and binaries from some chipset maker. I want to build the source of toolchain but I don't know the configure options/flags that were used to build the source. Is there any way so that I can get these options flags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try gcc -v.

This should give you the configure parameters.